# I have a problem with the wireless internet after I installed UBUNTU

Tags: wireless

I just installed Linux systems in my laptop, first Linux Mint so I have a problem while downloading any page using Firefox or any other web browser, then I installed UBUNTU 20.04.4 GNOME, but I still have the same problem. I discovered that it happens when I have the bluetooth speaker connected, when I disconnected it the wireless Wifi connection works good. I hope it is a problem with the networking card, the model I have on my laptop is Intel Centrino wireless N 1030. Does anyone have a manner to find the appropriate drivers?
Thank you!

Comment: You've provided no release details; Ubuntu LTS releases come with different kernel stack choices (the significance being *drivers* are actually kernel modules; thus differ when a different kernel stack is used).  Did you explore other *kernel stack* choices for your *unstated* Ubuntu release?

Comment: Thank you guiverc, you are right. The UBUNTU I have is GNOME, 20.04.4

Comment: FYI:  Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS Desktop can use the 5.4 kernel if you're using the GA kernel stack; or 5.13 if using the HWE kernel stack (*thus having different drivers*), or maybe using an alternate OEM kernel stack - the default is selected by what ISO you use to install your system (LTS releases more choices than non-LTS). You can use `uname -r` and the first two numbers (separated by a ".") are key; ie 5.4 = GA kernel stack, 5.13 = HWE, something else & OEM in the string shows an OEM kernel stack.  Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS provides some detail; not all - but you'll likely find you're using 5.13 HWE

Comment: Guiverc, thank you for your soon response, I did what you mentioned and in fact I am using 5.13 : "5.13.0-40 generic". Do you have an idea on where can I find the controllers? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because BT - Wi-Fi coexistence technology is not perfectly supported by Linux kernel for some Intel devices.

On most cases this can be fixed. Run in a terminal:

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-opt.conf <<< "options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=N"
```

and reboot.

The setting can be reversed by

```
sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-opt.conf
```

Comment: Dear Pilot6, Already ran the command you suggested, it didn't work, I have "options iwlwifi bt-coex.active=N" as response, but I still have no wifi connection while the Bluetooth is active. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Do you have the file `/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-opt.conf` with `options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=N` inside? Also check `dmesg`

Comment: options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=N is displayed after I ran the /etc/modprobe.d...... command